# In MondoDB : Slice array of objects from slicing index array and push in array through aggregation

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework, slice

I want to slice array in document according to slicingIndex key available in the same document and push into an array.

```
[
  {
    slicingIndex: [0, 4, 7, 10],
    array: [
      { name: 1 },
      { name: 2 },
      { name: 3 },
      { name: 4 },
      { name: 5 },
      { name: 6 },
      { name: 7 },
      { name: 8 },
      { name: 9 },
      { name: 10 }
    ]
  }
]
```

Output (expected):

```
{
  "array": [
    [
      { "name": 1 },
      { "name": 2 },
      { "name": 3 },
      { "name": 4 }
    ],
    [
      { "name": 5 },
      { "name": 6 },
      { "name": 7 }
    ],
    [
      { "name": 8 },
      { "name": 9 },
      { "name": 10 }
    ]
  ]
}
```

This is what aggregation i tried below but not working as expected:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      slicingIndex: 1,
      array: {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$slicingIndex",
          "as": "num",
          "in": {
            "$slice": [
              "$array",
              "$$num",
              {
                "$subtract": [
                  {
                    "$arrayElemAt": ["$slicingIndex", { "$indexOfArray": ["$slicingIndex", "$$num"] }]
                  },
                  "$$num"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MongoDb Playground Link** : https://mongoplayground.net/p/oNzBVLRfIU0

`$add` & `$indexOfArray` used to take **one step ahead element** from current pointer in array like (n+1). 
`$let` : I have used it as optional to make variable reusable if needed.
`$map` : To traverse array elements. 
`$arrayElemAt` : To get from element from array.
`$subtract` : To perform operation like **[ (n+1) - n ]** where n is index in array.
`$filter` : To filter out elements (in our case: **null**).

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      array: {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$slicingIndex",
          "as": "elem",
          "in": {
            "$let": {
              "vars": {
                //create variable that holds element one index+1 to the current index
                "elemOneStepHeadToElem": {
                  "$arrayElemAt": [
                    "$slicingIndex",
                    {
                      $add: [
                        1,
                        {
                          "$indexOfArray": [
                            "$slicingIndex",
                            "$$elem"
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              "in": {
                "$slice": [
                  "$array",
                  "$$elem",
                  {
                    "$subtract": [
                      "$$elemOneStepHeadToElem",
                      "$$elem"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }//remove null from array from last index
  ,
  {
    "$project": {
      array: {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$array",
          "cond": {
            $ne: [
              "$$this",
              null
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create two arrays for the pairs of the indexes for the slices, by zipping `slicingIndex` with itself. aka "zip with next".
   For the start index - take `n` elements where n = size minus 1. And for the end index, start from the end using `minus n` for `slice`.

   - this gives the arrays `startIndexes: [0, 4, 7]` and `endIndexes: [4, 7, 10]`
   - edit: Changed `multiply { subtract size 1 }, -1` to just `subtract 1 size` since `(n - 1) * -1 == 1 - n`
2. Then zip these two together to get Start & End index pairs.

   - `sliceIdxPairs` is `[[0, 4], [4, 7], [7, 10]]`
3. But since the params for [`$slice` aggregation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) are `position` (start index) and `n` (number of elements), what we need is to subtract the `endIndex` from the `startIndex` in each of the pairs.

   - `sliceParams` is `[[0, 4], [4, 3], [7, 3]]`
4. Finally, `$map` the pairs of numbers in the `sliceParams` and use them with `$slice` on the `array` field.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      array: 1,
      startIndexes: {
        $slice: [
          "$slicingIndex",
          { $subtract: [{ $size: "$slicingIndex" }, 1] }
        ]
      },
      endIndexes: {
        $slice: [
          "$slicingIndex",
          { $subtract: [1, { $size: "$slicingIndex" }] }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      array: 1,
      sliceIdxPairs: {
        $zip: { inputs: ["$startIndexes", "$endIndexes"] }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      array: 1,
      sliceParams: {
        $map: {
          input: "$sliceIdxPairs",
          as: "ip",
          in: [
            { $first: "$$ip" },
            { $subtract: [{ $last: "$$ip" }, { $first: "$$ip" }] }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      array: {
        $map: {
          input: "$sliceParams",
          as: "pair",
          in: {
            $slice: [
              "$array",
              { $first: "$$pair" },
              { $last: "$$pair" }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0G7r_n8L4cl)

Answer (score 1):

Tricky question!

You should start the iteration from the second element of `slicingIndex`. To slice the `array`, you need to get the (`$slice`) start index with the value of the previous element of the current iterated element (current index - 1) and the `n` should be current element - previous element.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      slicingIndex: 1,
      array: {
        "$map": {
          "input": {
            $slice: [
              "$slicingIndex",
              1,
              {
                $size: "$slicingIndex"
              }
            ]
          },
          "as": "num",
          "in": {
            "$slice": [
              "$array",
              {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                  "$slicingIndex",
                  {
                    $subtract: [
                      {
                        "$indexOfArray": [
                          "$slicingIndex",
                          "$$num"
                        ]
                      },
                      1
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                $subtract: [
                  "$$num",
                  {
                    "$arrayElemAt": [
                      "$slicingIndex",
                      {
                        $subtract: [
                          {
                            "$indexOfArray": [
                              "$slicingIndex",
                              "$$num"
                            ]
                          },
                          1
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qiy6TeYbLdF)

Comment: The second result in your current solution is `{name.... 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}`. It should be only `5, 6, 7`. But the first and last (`1, 2, 3, 4` and `8, 9, 10`) are correct.

Comment: Thanks @aneroid for pointing this out, I misslook, ya, I wonder whether is there any improvement as it seems I duplicated the way to get the previous element in 2 place.

Comment: Yes, I think you would _have to_ repeat that since there's no other way to get `$$num minus previous`. The only way I see around that is to create the pair before the final slice (either as a separate stage or as an inner array before doing the slicing). Will think over it a bit later. PS. This is the first time I tried to parse-with-eyes such a nested stage 